# Pyspark - update list in udf

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any possibility to update a list/variable inside an udf?

Let's consider this scenario:

```
studentsWithNewId = []

udfChangeStudentId = udf(changeStudentId, IntegerType())

def changeStudentId(studentId):

    if condition:
        newStudentId = computeNewStudentId() // this function is based on studentsWithNewId list contents
        studentsWithNewId.append(newStudentId)
        return newStudentId
    return studentId

studentsDF.select(udfChangeStudentId(studentId))
```

Is this possible and safe on a cluster environment?

The code above is just an example, therefore maybe it can be re-written in some other, better way.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to express this logic without a udf(udfs r slow in spark for big data). if u could provide sample data, and desired output, and logic u used for computeNewAsStudentId(), it would help others answer using spark inbuilt functions

Comment: @Hello Lili Have you got an answer to your question?